# RemoveAttr doesn't remove disabled

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
   <input type="checkbox" name="checking">j'accepte les conditions
   <input type="submit" value="Valider"  id="valide" disabled/>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

         if((input=$("input:checkbox[name=checking]").is(":checked"))){
            $("#valide").prop('disabled',true);
         }

});
    </script>
```

Hi, i want enable button (valide) when i checked checkbox

Comment: *"RemoveAttr doesn't remove disabled"* Nothing in your code is using `removeAttr` (which has a lower case `r`). Your code is correctly using `prop` to manipulate the `disabled` property.

Comment: Well that code is setting it to be disabled.....

Answer (score -3, accepted):

you must add listener to check box for call function every time when user check or uncheck it

try this sloution :)

```
   <input type="checkbox" onclick="check()" name="checking">j'accepte les            conditions
   <input type="submit" value="Valider"  id="valide" disabled/>





     function check(){
    if($('input[name=checking]').is(":checked")){
        $("#valide").prop('disabled',false);
    }else{
    $("#valide").prop('disabled',true);
    }
    }
```

please be sure to add javascript code after your html code

demo Click [here](http://jsfiddle.net/s1krr0jn/)

Comment: 1. It's best to hook up handlers using modern techniques, especially when using jQuery as it's so easy to do. 2. If you want to use the old `onXyz` attributes, at least pass `this` into the function so you can avoid the DOM lookup.

Answer (score 2):

Simply listen for the 'change' event on checkbox and enable/disable the button accordingly.

```
$("input:checkbox[name=checking]").on('change',function(){
     $("#valide").prop('disabled', !this.checked);        
})
```

Here's the [demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/Aq7fBdUAVgGG8MTHbeVp?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

So...respond to a click on the checkbox setting `disabled` to `false` if the checkbox is ticked. In this example, I'm assuming you *also* want to set `disabled` to `true` if the checkbox is unticked again:

```
if((input=$("input:checkbox[name=checking]").is(":checked"))){
    $("#valide").prop('disabled',true); // <== You might want to make this depend on the initial state of the checkbox
}
input.on("click", function() {
    $("#valide").prop('disabled', !this.checked);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Tushar490/u5r2bea1/) :

```
$(function () {
   $(':checkbox[name=checking]').click(function () {
      if ($(this).is(':checked')) $('#valide').prop('disabled', false);
   });
});
```